# Content-Ids not showing up in batch response

Tags: postman, odata

The Content-Ids I've setup in my odata batch request payload body are not showing up in the response payload body. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or missing? I am using postman to test. I am not sure if that is a factor in this.

Sample Request:

> ```
> --b2ef9c16-0c1f-47b4-942e-c5edd372bcc2
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=4df12e8f-048c-44f4-8003-1724637652e3
>
> --4df12e8f-048c-44f4-8003-1724637652e3
> Content-Type: application/http
> Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
> Content-Id: 1
>
> POST CreateChangeRequest HTTP/1.1
> Accept:application/json;odata.metadata=full;IEEE754Compatible=true
> Content-Type: application/json;IEEE754Compatible=true
>
> {"Init":true}
>
> --4df12e8f-048c-44f4-8003-1724637652e3
> Content-Type: application/http
> Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
> Content-Id: 2
>
> POST CustomerOrderSet(OrderNo='Z10068')/OrderLinesArray HTTP/1.1
> Accept:application/json;odata.metadata=full;IEEE754Compatible=true
> Content-Type: application/json;IEEE754Compatible=true
> X-IFS-Accept-Warnings: true
>
> {}
>
> --4df12e8f-048c-44f4-8003-1724637652e3
> Content-Type: application/http
> Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
> Content-Id: 3
>
> POST CreateChangeRequest HTTP/1.1
> Accept:application/json;odata.metadata=full;IEEE754Compatible=true
> Content-Type: application/json;IEEE754Compatible=true
>
> {"Init":false}
>
> --4df12e8f-048c-44f4-8003-1724637652e3--
> --b2ef9c16-0c1f-47b4-942e-c5edd372bcc2--
> ```

Sample Response:

> ```
> --batch_8c97ad06-3e3d-4ac5-9921-7137bb31bdb1
> Content-Type: application/http
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
> OData-Version: 4.0
> Content-Length: 0
> Content-Language: en-US
> Content-Length: 0
>
>
> --batch_8c97ad06-3e3d-4ac5-9921-7137bb31bdb1
> Content-Type: application/http
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
> OData-Version: 4.0
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 208
>
> {}
> --batch_8c97ad06-3e3d-4ac5-9921-7137bb31bdb1
> Content-Type: application/http
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
> OData-Version: 4.0
> Content-Length: 0
> Content-Language: en-US
> Content-Length: 0
>
>
> --batch_8c97ad06-3e3d-4ac5-9921-7137bb31bdb1--
> ```

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I assume that SAP Gateway handles your OData, right? If yes, I would look for logs/dumps/clues on the backend.

Comment: Not exactly, but I was lending toward it is a backend issue.